# Cloud animation looping in Css3

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a problem with css3 animation effect.
As a example. 
This clouds animates until 7 seconds, After that 7 seconds over,it comes to start point and animate again.
But when it come to start point, It shows like cloud come back and start animation.I want to stop that thing and only animate to one direction continuously.
anyone can help?

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo7csjnu/4/)

CSS3

```
.sky {
        height:638px;
        background:#007fd5;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        -webkit-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
        -moz-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
        -o-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }


    .moon {
        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/moon.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        height:85%;
        width:300%;
        -webkit-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }


    .clouds_one {
          margin-top: -55px;
        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_one.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        height:80%;
        width:400%;
        -webkit-animation:cloud_one 3s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:cloud_one 3s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:cloud_one 3s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    .clouds_two {
        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_two.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        height:80%;
        width:400%;
        -webkit-animation:cloud_two 4s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:cloud_two 4s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:cloud_two 4s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    .clouds_three {

        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_three.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        height:75%;
        width:400%;
        -webkit-animation:cloud_three 7s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:cloud_three 7s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:cloud_three 7s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
        0% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }

        50% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }

        100% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes moon {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            left:-200%
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
            left:0%
            bottom:250px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            bottom:500px;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes sky_background {
        0% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }

        50% {
            background:#000;
            color:#a3d9ff
        }

        100% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes moon {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            left:-200%
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
            left:0%
            bottom:250px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            bottom:500px;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cloud_one {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cloud_two {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cloud_three {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="sky">
  <div class="clouds_one"></div>
  <div class="clouds_two"></div>
  <div class="clouds_three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
    0% {
        left:100%
    }

    100% {
        left:-100%
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
    0% {
        left:100&
    }

    100% {
        left:-100%
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
    0% {
        left:+100%
    }

    100% {
        left:-100%
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine,if you want fast animation decrease animation time and if you want clouds from moving from large distance ,change 100% to 150%

Comment: increase the time to slow down,so all the screen stays until it goes away

Comment: Still this still not working Sai, can you update fiddle pleaseee

Answer (score 0):

try this code..
**CSS**

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds{
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #c9dbe9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}

/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/
.cloud {
    width: 200px; height: 60px;
    background: #fff;

    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
    background: #fff;
    width: 100px; height: 80px;
    position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;

    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

/*Time to animate*/
.x1 {
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
    left: 200px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
    opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
    /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
    left: -250px; top: -200px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
    left: 470px; top: -250px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
    left: -150px; top: -150px;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/

    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

Reference from: http://jsfiddle.net/vampireneo/Bt5VN/

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body {
   margin:0;
   height:100%
  }
  
  .sky {
   height:480px;
   background:#007fd5;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   -webkit-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
   -moz-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
   -o-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
   -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
  }
  
  
  .moon {
   background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/moon.png");
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   height:100%;
   width:300%;
   -webkit-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
   -o-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
   -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
  }
  
  
  .clouds_one {
   background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_one.png");
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   height:100%;
   width:300%;
   -webkit-animation:cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation:cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
   -o-animation:cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
   -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
  }
  
  .clouds_two {
   background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_two.png");
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   height:100%;
   width:300%;
   -webkit-animation:cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation:cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
   -o-animation:cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
   -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
  }
  
  .clouds_three {
   background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_three.png");
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   height:100%;
   width:300%;
   -webkit-animation:cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation:cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
   -o-animation:cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
   -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
   0% {
    background:#007fd5;
    color:#007fd5
   }
   
   50% {
    background:#000;
    color:#a3d9ff
   }
   
   100% {
    background:#007fd5;
    color:#007fd5
   }
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes moon {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left:-200%
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
   }
   
   50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    left:0%
    bottom:250px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   }
  
   100% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom:500px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
   }
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
   0% {
    left:0
   }
  
   100% {
    left:-200%
   }
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
   0% {
    left:0
   }
  
   100% {
    left:-200%
   }
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
   0% {
    left:0
   }
  
   100% {
    left:-200%
   }
  }
  
  @-moz-keyframes sky_background {
   0% {
    background:#007fd5;
    color:#007fd5
   }
   
   50% {
    background:#000;
    color:#a3d9ff
   }
   
   100% {
    background:#007fd5;
    color:#007fd5
   }
  }
  
  @-moz-keyframes moon {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left:-200%
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
   }
   
   50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    left:0%
    bottom:250px;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   }
  
   100% {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom:500px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
   }
  }
  
  @-moz-keyframes cloud_one {
   0% {
    left:0
   }
  
   100% {
    left:-200%
   }
  }
  
  @-moz-keyframes cloud_two {
   0% {
    left:0
   }
  
   100% {
    left:-200%
   }
  }
  
  @-moz-keyframes cloud_three {
   0% {
    left:0
   }
  
   100% {
    left:-200%
   }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Improved Cloud</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sky">
     
     <div class="moon"></div>
    
        <div class="clouds_one"></div>

        <div class="clouds_two"></div>

        <div class="clouds_three"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Working Perfectly fine just test the code snippet.